# How to prevent a process started by Process.Start() from exiting when my app exits?

Tags: c#, process, process.start

my method...

```
private static void RunAndExit(string command)
{
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "/c " + command,
        CreateNoWindow = false,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        RedirectStandardError = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = false
     };
    }
```

I want the process started by RunAndExit() to continue to run after the app containing this method has exited. Thanks for any help!

Comment: ops I doubt that you can achieve this  due to windows architecture

Comment: How are you starting it?

Comment: What kind of app is the parent? Console or GUI?

Comment: The child process isn't exiting because its parent exited.  It may be exiting because its standard input and output streams started producing errors.

Comment: I realize now that vstest.console is part of the issue. This code is part of a unit test. If I run the unit test through vstest.console.exe (replacement for MSTest) the process will go away when vstest.console exits. If, however, I run this test from Visual Studio test explorer, it will not go away when the test is finished nor when I close Visual Studio.

Comment: also, I made an error in copying the code over. There is a call to Process.Start(processInfo) in the real code.

Comment: Well, I guess I answered the question you asked based on the code you provided.

Comment: Yes you did David. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will already achieve that, so long as you actually start the new process. You are missing a call to `Process.Start()`.

```
private static void RunAndExit(string command)
{
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        ....
    };
    Process.Start(processInfo); // add this line
}
```